Regarding basis of a vector space
Given a non-zero vector $u_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$, one can choose an arbitrary vector $u_{arb} \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ ($u_{arb}$ and $u_1$ are linearly independent)  and take cross product of $u_1$ and $u_{air}$ to define $u_2 = u_1 \times u_{arb}$. Clearly $u_1$ and $u_2$ are orthogonal. Similarly, let's define $u_3 = u_2 \times u_1$, so that $u_1$, $u_2$ and $u_3$ now form an orthogonal pair of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and hence are linearly independent.
Questions:

Does $\{u_1, u_2, u_3 \}$ form a basis in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$? In other words, does every orthogonal set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ span this space?
If $1$ is true, can one construct such basis from a single vector for higher dimensional spaces as well, say $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $\mathbb{C}^{n}$, using some analogue of cross product?



yes unless $u_1$ and $u_{arb}$ are linearly dependent 2. how do you define the cross product in higher dimension spaces?


${u_1,u_2,u_3}$ is not necessarily a linearly independent set of vectors, because $u_2=u_3=0$ when $u_1=0$ or when your “arbitrary vector” is a scalar multiple of $u_1$.


Yes, any 3 non-zero vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that are mutually orthogonal span the space.

It depends on what you mean by an 'analog' of the cross product. In $\mathbb{R}^n$, given any collection of mutually orthogonal vectors $x_1, ... , x_k$ with $k<n$, it can always be extended by one more vector that is orthogonal to all of the given vectors. It is peculiar to $\mathbb{R}^3$ that given $x_1$ and $x_2$ orthogonal, a third vector $x_3$ can be found orthogonal to both of these with a type of 'multiplication'. In higher dimensions, all of the vectors $x_1, ... , x_k$ are needed to determine the next vector, and there is no simple formula you can plug the components of the vectors into to do the computation.


